# How can I use a case statement with a Drop Box? Access Database

Tags: database, ms-access-2007, dropdownbox, sql, iif-function

I have a drop box with various items when the value is set to null I want to select multiple items using the control parameter to fill the data source like below. 
 This Select Command will not work can anyone help me to see what I'm doing in error? EDIT THE CODE BELOW IS NOW CORRECT AND FUNCTIONS.....

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="FilterList1" runat="server">

                    <asp:ListItem  Selected="True" Value=" ">Produce</asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem>Fruits</asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem>Vegetables</asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem>Milk</asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem>Pop</asp:ListItem>

</asp:DropDownList>
<asp:AccessDataSource ID="AccessDataSource1" runat="server" 
    DataFile="~/AFOLDER/db1.mdb" 
    SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM [Table1] WHERE IIF( (@Food1 ='  '), [Food] In ('Fruit','Vegetable'), (Food =@Food1) )">
    <SelectParameters>
      <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="FilterList1" Name="Food1" 
            PropertyName="SelectedValue" Type="String" />
    </SelectParameters>
</asp:AccessDataSource>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you are using `AccessDataSource1`, then try Access SQL `IIF()` Statement, something like:

```
SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM [Table1] WHERE (Service =@Service1) OR IIF((@Service1 ='  '), IIF( [Service] In ('In Service','Out of Service'), True, False), False)
```

Also, make sure you are using correct syntax `@Service1 ='  '` (may be `@Service1 =''` ?)

Hope this will help.

Regards

Comment: `@Service1 ='  '` is correct syntax. This answer did not work but may be a step in the right direction.

Comment: So it works like this.     
        `SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM [Table1] WHERE (Service =@Service1) OR IIF( (@Service1 ='  '), [Service] In ('In Service','Out of Service'), (Service =@Service1) )">`

Comment: I would also suggest putting the above answer at the bgining of the where statement. I had trouble putting it at end the of a very long where statement.

Comment: I have fixed the above question to work as it should hope it helps someone. Good luck happy programing.